# Multidimensional array insert into mysql

Tags: php, arrays

I have this kind of array:

```
Array
(
    [date] => 
    [contract_num] => 43543 
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Michael
            [1] => Jack
        )

    [birthday] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1.2.2001.
            [1] => 3.6.2005.
        )

    [address] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [telephone] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 22
        )
)
```

I'm struggling with inserting in to database birthday, address & telephone.
How can I rearrange this array to insert data into database with this rows:

- id
- name
- birthday
- address
- telephone

Comment: what flavor of database?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: MySQL and php, I thing I need php array expert here

Comment: Is this array input from an HTML form? If so, you could name your form inputs so that you'd get more usable arrays in $_POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure the array is always consistent, i.e.:

- The fields (`name` etc.) are always the same
- All keys in all fields are always consistent

Then you can use this code:

```
$keys = array_keys($array['name']);
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $row = [
        'id' => $key,
        'name' => $array['name'][$key],
        'birthday' => $array['birthday'][$key],
        'address' => $array['address'][$key],
        'telephone' => $array['telephone'][$key],
    ];

    //Insert $row into your database. This depends on your setup.

}
```

If not, i.e. if the array might deviate from the structure you have given, please outline this in the question.